# Breaking a file down of strings, into separate files each based on the first letter. BASH

Tags: bash, script, parsing

Alright, so I have a file full of thousands of strings. Each one on it's own line. I want to make a script that will allow me to take this file, call it `list.txt`, and take the items from each line, and place it into separate files based on the first letter or number. As an example, say the first few lines of the file are like this:

```
cheese
pizza
pepperoni
lettuce
grahamCrackers
0-0Foods
chicken
lentils
1-2Items
```

I need to break it down into these:

### c.txt

```
cheese
chicken
```

### g.txt

```
grahamCrackers
```

### l.txt

```
lettuce
lentils
```

### p.txt

```
pizza
pepperoni
```

### 0.txt

```
0-0Foods
```

### 1.txt

```
1-2Items
```

I would like to accomplish this with BASH, on OS X. Thanks.

Oh, if it helps. Items on each line will NEVER have a space, they will always be contained as one word. E.G. (Never Chicken Soup, instead Chicken-Soup)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS='
'
typeset -a file
file=($(cat list.txt))
for i in "${file[@]}"; do
    echo $i >> ${i:0:1}.txt
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Note, the IFS part is not usually necessary. Also, I tested it on Zsh 4.3.17 on linux and on Bash 4.2.37.

What it does is it declares an array, assigns the contents of the file to that array, then loops over each element of the array, hence each line and echo's that element into the file with the name of the first lettes plus '.txt' appended to it.

Comment: I just tried using that exact code and just replaced list.txt with my file. However, it took awhile, but after it was done. Nothing happened. Was I suppose to do something else?

Comment: No, it works for me out of the box. Try 'set -x' and then run the command, and pastebin the output, perhaps I can help then.

Comment: One thing though, is there a way you can put these outputed files in a folder first.

Comment: Yes, 'mkdir' that folder first, then change '${i:0:1}.txt' to 'folder/${i:0:1}.txt'

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot. But I have one more for you... (I can't make this too easy. ;) ) Say I want to divide based on the first two letters, can that be easily accomplished?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Whoa... this is much more elegant than the grep/sed-based solution I was going to write up. It's always surprising what bash can do by itself. With that said, you can avoid messing around with $IFS & generally simplify things by using a while loop instead of that for loop. Replace `for i in "${file[@]}"; do` with `while read i; do`, and replace `done` with `done <list.txt`, and then you can ditch all the stuff outside of the loop.

Comment: @evilsoup you can't beat `gawk` for simplicity when it comes to this sort of thing. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 8):

You could just use gawk and simplify things:

```
gawk '{n=substr($1,0,1); print >> n".txt"}' file.txt
```

- `n=substr($1,0,1)` takes a substring of length 1 starting from the first position (0) of the first field (`$1`) and saves it into a variable called `n`.
- `print >> n".txt"` will append (`>>`) each line into a text file called `n.txt` (where `n` is the first letter).

To do the same thing for the first two letters, just change the length of `substr`:

```
gawk '{n=substr($1,0,2); print >> n".txt"}' file.txt
```

Comment: Cool, this is a good answer too. +1!

Comment: Do not forget to `close()` if your `awk` stumbled with "too many open files" error, e.g. `gawk '{n=substr($1,0,2); print >> n".txt"; close(n".txt")}' file.txt`

Comment: thankyou for this, I used the two letter one on my dictionary of 450k words. I thought it hadn't worked when the command finished instantly, but they're all there!!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    firstChar=${line:0:1}
    fileName=${firstChar}.txt
    if [ -e ${fileName} ];then
    touch ${fileName}
     fi
    echo ${line} >> ${fileName}
done < list.txt
```

The above script takes the first character of each line read in from the `list.txt` file. It then attempts to create a file with that character + ".txt", and then append each line from `list.txt` to the appropriate character + ".txt" file.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly create the file; the `>>` will create it if it does not exist (unless `noclobber` has been set, in which case unset it for the script)

Comment: Not only do you not need to create it, you are also not creating it at all. `-e` means check if the file exists and you will only `touch` the file if that is true. All you are doing is modifying the file's creation date if the file exists.